# Access FileUploader value inside Ajax UploadPanel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using simple ASP.Net File Up loader inside an AJAX Update Panel. 
But I am not accessing the Path and File Name
Can you help me to solve the issue and Suggest if any other way.

Thanx and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Basically, file upload does not work inside the UpdatePanel.

But what do you want to access exactly? You cannot get the path of the client file anyway.

Comment: actually I want to upload the client file into server. But I have to use it inside update panel. is this possible. if not is there any other way. plz suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As Remy states above, uploading files within an update is not possible.

You can make use of a PostBackTrigger within your UpdatePanel:

[PostBackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger.aspx)

The above MSDN article contains a code listing for using a PostBackTrigger with a FileUpload control.

Other approaches available to you are to use an iframe on a separate page (see: [ASP.NET - Upload File With Loading Image using JavaScript and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FileUploadingWithLoading.aspx)) or to use one of the many third party components out there which make use of javascript and flash to upload files (Find links to a couple of the more popular ones below)

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com)

[SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use ASP.NET AJAX ControlToolkit AsynFileUpload

[AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Postback trigger in update panel like this:

```
<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="SubmitButtonId" />
</Triggers>
```

Hope this will help, Please let me know for any issues